# как сделать одноразовую проверку нажатой клавиши?

Tags: python, база-данных, клавиатура

Мне нужно чтобы при запуске программы я нажал на любую клавишу, эта клавиша сохранилась в переменную в питоне и в базе данных, а затем программа остановилась.

```
import sqlite3
import keyboard

a = ''

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    global a
    a = e.name
    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotkey (key1 TEXT)''')
        query = f""" UPDATE hotkey SET key1 = '{a}' """
        cursor.execute(query)
        db.commit()

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait(a)
print(a)
```

В базе данных клавиша сохраняется, но с переменной в питоне проблема.
И программа не останавливается после одного нажатия.
(мне не нужно ставить остановку программы на определенную клавишу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как я уже выяснил, функция read_key в данном случае будет подходить

```
import keyboard
print(keyboard.read_key())
```

Comment: я вам об этом писал в начале цикла вопросов)

Comment: знаю, просто продублировал ваше решение здесь

Answer (score 2):

Неправильно вы с SQL работаете

Не:

```
query = f""" UPDATE hotkey SET key1 = '{a}' """
cursor.execute(query)
```

А:

```
query = "UPDATE hotkey SET key1 = ?"
cursor.execute(query, (a,))
```

Разница в том, что используется биндинг-параметров и драйвер базы может подготовить запрос, сделав нужное экранирование или трансформацию данных (например, объект даты-время превратить в строку/число, что понимает база данных)

А для остановки приложения можно использовать [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Comment: а куда нужно поместить этот sys.exit()?

Comment: @MIkhail, думаю, после `db.commit()`

Comment: тогда программа просто закрывается

Comment: @MIkhail, `а затем программа остановилась` мне показалось, что вам это и нужно :D Если не нужно чтобы в дальнейшем была обработка, то добавьте глобальный флаг = `False`, в функции `print_pressed_keys` проверяйте его значение и если `True`, то выходите из функции, а после `db.commit()` присвойте ему `True`